# How can I use System.Web.Optimization (.net js bundler) with amd modules?

Tags: javascript, .net, amd, bundling-and-minification, system.web.optimization

Now I am working with the project using `System.Web.Optimization` as js bundler.

How can I use `amd` modules with this bundler?

```
define('myModule', function(myModule){})
```

Now I am obviously getting `define is not defined` error.
Webpack and r.js can handle dependencies, but I dont want to change bundler yet.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK System.Web.Optimization is deprecated and there is no method to support it "from the box". Now I am using webpack with es6 modules. I am using [this extension](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebPackTaskRunner) to run webpack.